# Match Strings in One folder and redirect to other folder with parts of query string htaccess

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, azure

from

`http://www.example.com/oldfolder/subfolder/tour-from-**X**-to-**Y**/`

to

`http://www.example.com/newfolder/ **X** / **Y** /`

I could not figure out how to search for a string ['tour-from-**X**-to-**Y**'] and then redirect. Please help me. [**.HTACCESS**]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^oldfolder/subfolder/tour-from-([^-]+)-to-([^/]+)/?$ /newfolder/$1/$2/ [NC,L,R=302]
```